# Can I get result from javascript and use it in vb.net?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I have this code to show `confirm message` using `vb.net`, but I want to get the return result and use it in `vb.net` code.

```
   Dim str As String = "<script>" &
                        "$('.test').live('click',function(){" &
                        "confirm('test');" &
                         "})</script>"
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(control, GetType(Button), "sas", str, False)
```

I am thinking in storing the result data in `html compnent` and use it in `vb.net` code, is there another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result in a hidden field (`<input type="hidden">`), then retrieve it in your code after postback.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. The server side code is outputting text down a one-way channel. The JavaScript is running on a different system. You can't get data from the JS to the server without making a new HTTP request.

See also [Using Pylons global variables with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834666/using-pylons-global-variables-with-javascript-escaping-brackets/8834713#8834713) which is the same problem, just with a different language.