# Get value from select with JavaScript for use in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have this `select`:

```
<select id="mymenu" name="id" onchange="getID()">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value from `mymenu` to use it in another `select` in the same form. I searched the 'net and found that I should use `onchange`.

```
<select name="uid">
    <option></option>
<?
$sql = mysql_query("Select * from $table WHERE id = '$ch_id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
?>
    <option value="<? echo $row['unit_id']; ?>"><? echo $row['unit_name'];?></option>
<?
}
?>
</select>
```

This is the getID() function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getChapterID(){ //run some code when "onchange" event fires
var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu")
<?$ch_id?> = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
}
</script>
```

Comment: maybe it's `<?=$ch_id?>` Anyway use jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Pylons  global variables with JavaScript (escaping brackets)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834666/using-pylons-global-variables-with-javascript-escaping-brackets) — The details are different, but the root problem (Server side code runs THEN client side code runs) is the same, as is the solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

google "ajax php select menu", the first example here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

explains the process...

Beware the w3 demo though, it does not sanitize $_GET[] variable, and is wide open to a sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redefine a PHP value thru JS, it would be very unsafe. I suggest you to use kind of form that when you change it, it submits, posts into a php self and redefines it. I won't write that code for you, but this is what you need.

Good luck